# Create a 7 Day Running Total and Running Average

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet tracking figures day by day. I want to add a column with a 7 day running total (sum of last 6 rows plus current row) and a column with a 7 day running average (average of last 6 rows plus current row).

I've managed to create a running total fine (Say numbers in column `A`, then `B1 = A, B2 = B1 + A2` and drag the formula down to copy), but can't work out a 7 day running total.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the answer given useful?

Comment: Given I answered my own question in the end, yes :)

Comment: LOL, way to go dude(tte)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I gave in too fast.

7 day running total: `=Sum(Filter(D2:D8,A2:A8<=A8,A2:A8>A8-7))`

Filter returns a range of data, filtered based on multiple (can have more than 2 conditions). In the case I'm returning `D2:D8` (my count column) filtered where `A2:A8` (my date column) is less than the current date (`A8`) and greater than the current date - 7 days. Stick this in the 7th cell, and drag the cell out to manipulate the formulae into the following cells.

Then for 7 day running average (assuming the above in `F`) `G8 = F8 / 7` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a better running average would basically use the same date filtering you did for your sum, but using average instead.  Based on your sum function, I think your running seven day average would look something like this:
`=Average(Filter(F2:F8,A2:A8<=A8,A2:A8>A8-7))`

Noticed this while trying to accomplish nearly the exact same thing as you.